# Fast reading, writing of png images

Tags: performance-tuning, export, import, image, undocumented

One of the fastest implemented mathematica function to read png images was showed  [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138478/extraction-of-specific-image-pixels-as-bytes) by [MarcoB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27951/marcob)

The code for reading a png he proposed is:

```
First@Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG[imageFileName];
```

Following this I tried out if `ImageWritePNG` exists and indeed, one can use:

```
Image`ImportExportDump`ImageWritePNG[imageFileName, image];
```

**How can I find information that ImageReadPNG and ImageWritePNG exist and how they are used?**

Comment: This looks like two separate questions, and the second may be a duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18335/how-to-efficiently-import-videos).

Comment: @Simon Woods: thank you for the comment, I remove the avi part ... thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that those are *internal* functions which means what WRI can change them at any time without notice.

Comment: @Edmund: Thank you for the info. But a factor 4 or better (in my tests) in speed increase for reading is something very useful when you have to import many thousands files. By the way it shows how ineffective it can be for certain purposes to rely on the standard functions (here `Import[image]`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way you might find such a function.

*Mathematica* generally has descriptive names even for undocumented internal functions, so you can often find useful things by searching for appropriate substrings in symbol names. For example:

```
(* do a PNG import to make sure relevant functions are loaded *)
Import["any.png"];

(* search for symbols containing "PNG" *)
?*`*PNG*
```

[image]

One of the symbols is `` Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG `` which sounds like it might be useful. Check if we can see the definition:

```
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG]
```

[image]

In this case there is nothing useful here.

To see if (and how) the function is used during a PNG import, use `Trace`:

```
Trace[Import["any.png"], Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG[___], 
  TraceInternal -> True]
```

> `` {{{Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG["any.png"]}}} ``

So it looks like the function just takes the filename as an argument. Next you can test it and time it to find out if it's any better than simply using `Import`.

This is the sort of approach you need to take to uncover undocumented functions - there is inevitably an element of trial and error and often you will find nothing useful at all. Of course you should always save your work before this kind of experimentation.

Comment: This answer is great ... thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The 11.1 seem have accelerated the speed of importing.