# Import Integer images using Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF

Tags: image-processing

I can import 70000 x 2MB TIFF images (~140GB) using

> Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF

in about 3 minutes  [based on @Szabolcs solution to this question by @Kagaratsch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140974/quickly-importing-several-thousands-of-jpg-files) which is fantastic.

However, the image data is converted to floating point numbers <1.

Is there an option for Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF  which will preserve the original integer image data?

I tried using the options "Data", "Bit16", "Automatic" which returned $Failed.

Comment: Hard to help without the actual file. Can you upload your image somewhere and post a link?

Comment: Please try to put a *TIFF* file somewhere we can access it, then include code that shows what you expect to get back and what you actually get back.

Comment: @DrBubbles you posted a PNG not a TIFF

Comment: Sorry, I will generate one inline when I get back to my desk

Comment: Generating the code to create the image data and re-display it highlighted the issue and solved the question :-) Thanks Jason and M.R.

Comment: But maybe there is a way to speed things up further as I only need the ImageData so once imported it would be fine to stay as data and not an image.

Comment: @DrBubbles - if you solved your problem, consider moving the **Update** section to a self-answer if you think this will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**
Just found the problem was my use of ImageData[].  I thought I needed to export the data with "Bit16", I didn't realize (or forgot) I needed to use it with ImageData[] too.  Now I get the expected 16 bit integers in import using `` Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF `` :

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
im1 = Image[RandomInteger[{0, 65535}, {512, 512}], "Bit16"];
Export["im1.tiff", im1];
im2 = Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF[
AbsoluteFileName["im1.tiff"]][[1]];
ImageData[im1, "Bit16"][[1, 1]]
ImageData[im2, "Bit16"][[1, 1]]
```