# Weird behaviour of Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG

Tags: export, import, files-and-directories

Here is the problematic code,

```
g = Binarize@
   ImageResize[Rasterize[Plot[Sin[1 x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}]], {100, 100}];
Image`ImportExportDump`ImageWritePNG["D:\\g.png", g];
Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadPNG["D:\\g.png"]
```

Now, I think an animated gif would demonstrate the weird buggy behaviour better.

[image]

Is it intended behaviour of undocumented `ImportExportDump`? Why do we need to `Import` twice to release the somewhat cache issue? What is the workaround if we want fast import and export PNG multiple times to same file path?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue in 13.3 (see [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg9qG.gif)). Also, does [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/187787/75628) help? Although it seems ```Image`ImportExportDump`DeleteCachePNG[]``` is not available in v13 anymore ... Hmm ...

Comment: @Domen Saves my day! Thank you so much! Image`ImportExportDump`DeleteCachePNG[] works on 13.2. But I am wondering why you can't reproduce it.

Comment: @Domen You are right. I checked `DeleteCachePNG` is removed right after version 13.2. They probably integrate `DeleteCachePNG[]` into `ImageReadPNG` now.

Comment: That was my thought exactly, yeah. Nice catch. I guess you should write an answer about this find :)